# Fast mouse movement on jQuery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a simple dropdown item as

```
$('.item').mouseover(function(){
 $(this).children().slideDown('slow'); 
 });
$('.item').mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).children().slideUp("slow");
 });
```

My problem is that if we move mouse on/out the item rapidly for several times, it will perform all processes by continuing opening and closing the `<div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html), it specifically addresses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

check this jQuery function to stop animations - http://api.jquery.com/stop/